install and import theano.tensor
How to install theano.tensor?
I am attaching the program code below:
pip install theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np

N = 100
with pm.Model() as model:
    p = pm.Uniform("freq_cheating", 0, 1)
with model:
    true_answers = pm.Bernoulli("truths", p, shape=N, testval=np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, N))
with model:
    first_coin_flips = pm.Bernoulli("first_flips", 0.5, shape=N, testval=np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, N))

with model:
    second_coin_flips = pm.Bernoulli("second_flips", 0.5, shape=N, testval=np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, N))

with model:
    val = first_coin_flips*true_answers + (1 - first_coin_flips)*second_coin_flips
    observed_proportion = pm.Deterministic("observed_proportion", tt.sum(val)/float(N))

Please help me. Below is a description of the error. Below is a description of the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-82b00d491f91> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install Theano')
----> 2 import theano.tensor as tt

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py in __getattr__(attr)
    317 
    318         if attr in __former_attrs__:
--> 319             raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])
    320 
    321         if attr == 'testing':

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool'.
`np.bool` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `bool`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `bool` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.bool_` here.
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations 


This problem should be simple.
Have you checked if you downloaded the Python package using pip?
If not, in your terminal, type:
pip install Theano

This should help you resolve your issue.
For more issues, this is the Documentation.

I m edited questions.
